# Getting the unique values out of the two columns in a unique way in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

Supposing all I have is the column A and B below

```
               +             +
     A         |    B        |    C
+--------------|-------------|----------+
               |             |
  Service1     | Language1   |     Service1 in multiple Languages, & Service2 in Language1
  Service1     | Language2   |
  Service1     | Language3   |     
               |             |
  Service2     | Language1   |     
               +             +
```

How do I generate what is in cell C2 above - basically what it is doing is - it is first grabbing the 1st service, and if it has multiple values in B against it, then instead of taking all the values from B, it is calling it multiple Languages. However, once it gets a service which is in the single language, then it mentions the language name itself (as in Service2 row above).

Another example is as below for better clarity:

```
               +             +
     A         |    B        |    C
+--------------|-------------|----------+
               |             |
  Service1     | Language1   |     Service1 in Language1, & Service2 in multiple Languages
               |             |
  Service2     | Language2   |     
  Service2     | Language3   |
  Service2     | Language4   |     
               +             +
```

**Please note that** sometimes the table has more than 2 services (upto 5 services) and sometimes it is limited to only one service.

```
               +             +
     A         |    B        |    C
+--------------|-------------|----------+
               |             |
  Service1     | Language1   |     Service1 in in multiple Languages
               |             |
  Service1     | Language2   |     
  Service1     | Language3   |
  Service1     | Language4   |     
               +             +
```

Here is the link of a published spreadsheet with the above data : https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1XdcKbxKvIOSFK37zwULZns6giE9ounHPS5iHrRFkvIk/edit#gid=2041021291

Note: there is no gap of the row between Service1 and Service2, the gap is given here for better look and understanding of the data.

Answer (score 0):

For **two** `Service`s only:

```
=A2&" in "&if(countif(A:A,A2)>1,"multiple Languages",B2)&", & Service2 in "&if(countif(A:A,"Service2")>1,"multiple Languages",vlookup("Service2",A:B,2,0))
```

Comment: Thanx for your response, and my apologies for not being clear enough : sometimes it does have more than 2 services (upto 5 services) and sometimes it is limited to only one service (your formula gives error when it is limited to Service1). I am going to add this info on the question.